# onLongpress in android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am trying out a small project where I using ontouch listener which uses the motion event. Everytime I move my finger on the screen a different sound is played. Which works perfectly without any issue. Now I am trying to do another process - when I long press on the screen immediately after I stop moving (without removing my fingure) - I need another new activity to opened.  Hence I was trying to use onlongpress event but onlongpress didn't seem to work - as i believe OnTouchListener and SimpleOnGestureListener doesn't go well together. With these only one works - touchlistner or SimpleonGesture?

Hence I tried out my own logic by not using the longpress but by a countdown timer. Check if oldmove and newmove's are equal (x and y value are same for say 2 seconds) if so triggers the new activity. the logic works perfect but the problem is that even after the activity is opened - the same activity is opened again and again. Not sure why?

I also tried to cancel the counter tread before the counter starts - what happens is that result come out late - I mean instead 2 seconds it takes 10 seconds but comes twice or thrice again and again.

```
  OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener= new OnTouchListener()
{

    public boolean onTouch(View view, final MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();    
            down = x+y;
            break;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {

            int move= (int) (event.getX() + event.getY()); 

            if(Math.abs(down-move)>125 && Math.abs(down-move)<300 )
            {
                if(counter!=null)
                {
                    counter.cancel();
                }

                if(longpressCount==1)
                {
                    soundPool.play(id1, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                else if(longpressCount==2)
                {
                    soundPool.play(id2, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                else if(longpressCount==3)
                {
                    soundPool.play(id3, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                else if(longpressCount==4)
                {
                    soundPool.play(id4, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                    longpressCount = 0;
                }

                down =   (int) (event.getX() + event.getY());
                move1 =  (int) (event.getX() + event.getY());
                    longpressCount++;

                }
            else if((Math.abs(move1-move))<20)
            {
                Log.e("STARTING COUNTER", "");
                counter = new CountDownTimer(2000, 2000) 
                {

                    int mold =(int) (event.getX() + event.getY());

                    public void onFinish() 
                    {
                        int mnew = (int) (event.getX() + event.getY());

                        if(Math.abs(mold-mnew)<30)
                        {
                            Log.e("Current longpressCount", longpressCount+"");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
                    {

                    }

                }.start();
            }

            break;
        }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

What do you think the problem is? I am not able to achieve my logic?

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why did you summed the x and y coordinates?

Comment: So that I can differentiate the old and new values for the condition.

Comment: Yes, but you add the x coordinate with the y coordinate. Shouldn't you calculate the difference between the old X and the new X(and for Y the same) separately from the other coordinate?

Comment: Yep. I am doing the same instead what I am doing is adding both X and Y put that in down and move's x and y value add them and put them in move